# How to pass date and time to a structure variable using C

Tags: c, linux, struct

I have a structure called

```
struct binary
{
  uint32_t time;
  uint16_t id;
  uint8_t data[8];
};
```

and inside my function to read CAN frames i have my structure variable called bin.

```
struct binary bin;
```

and when i assign time to my structure as follows

```
bin.time = tm-> tm_mon+1"."tm->tm_mday"_"tm->tm_hour":"tm->tm_min":"tm->tm_sec;
```

it shows an error message

```
error:expected ';' before string constant 
bin.time = tm-> tm_mon+1"."tm->tm_mday"_"tm->tm_hour":"tm->tm_min":"tm->tm_sec;
```

How can I pass time to the structure member time since later i want to use the following structure in my fwrite function as follows:

```
fwrite(&bin,sizeof(bin),1,fPtr);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not Java. Try with `sprintf`. `sprintf(bin.time,"%d%c%d%c%d%c%d%c%d",m->tm_mon+1,".",tm->tm_mday,"_",tm->tm_hour,":",tm->tm_min,":",tm->tm_sec);` Finnally you can `atoi` the string.

Comment: I need to do it in binary...need to write binary data to the file.

Comment: as time is an integer you might want to write a number into it not a string.

Comment: Can I use sprintf with a buffer of size 32 bit?

Comment: What do you think `bin.time = tm-> tm_mon+1"."tm->tm_mday"_"tm->tm_hour":"tm->tm_min":"tm->tm_sec;` is doing?  `.time` is not a string yet you are incorrectly trying to build one.

Comment: Since `bin.time` just holds a number from 0 to 0xFFFFFFFF, you need to calculate a value to put in there. You could use `bin.time = mktime(&tm);` to calculate the number of elapsed seconds since Jan 1, 1970. Is that any use to you?

Comment: `sprintf(bin.time,"%d%c%d%c%d%c%d%c%d",m->tm_mon+1,".",tm->tm_mday,"_",tm->tm_hour,":",tm->tm_min,":",tm->tm_sec);` It shows a warning message called expected 'char *' restrict but argument is of type 'uint32_t{aka unsigned int}

Comment: It's only a warning not an error @sp5.

Comment: Yeah saving as a string into a buffer first and then converting into a HEX?

Comment: It seems like you are struggling with the basics of C. I suggest reading a book or a tutorial.

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) but do learn C programming... You might be interested by [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) and [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)

Comment: Yeah very useful, thankyou

Comment: I remember 32-bit time.  We used to use that in 1980, I think.

Comment: May I know how can I use that?

Comment: integers are in binary format already - that's how computers store information in their memory

Comment: Can I simply call `_time32(__time32_t); // to get 32bit time_t` in my program to store the time into my bin.time? And then writing into the file?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `sprintf(bin.time,"%d%c...",m->tm_mon+1,".",...` should use `'.'` rather than `"."`.

Comment: Yes, but that should be detected by the compiler (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`)

Answer (score 1):

> when i assign time to my structure as follows

```
// bin.time is a uint32_t
bin.time = tm-> tm_mon+1"."tm->tm_mday"_"tm->tm_hour":"tm->tm_min":"tm->tm_sec;
```

Certainly this is meant to save a `struct tm` as a `time_t`.

If `tm` is a *local* time then use

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t t = mktime(tm);
if (t == (time_t)-1) {
  Handle_conversion_failure();
}
if (t < 0 || t > UINT32_MAX) {
  Handle_range_failure();
}
bin.time = (uint32_t) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement is wrong:-

```
bin.time = tm-> tm_mon+1"."tm->tm_mday"_"tm->tm_hour":"tm->tm_min":"tm->tm_sec;
```

To store the above values you have to change your time to an string like below:-

```
char time[30];//uint32_t time; As you are new to C I ma not using a char pointer here.
```

Now in the code:-

```
strcpy(time, itoa(tm->tm_mon+1));
strcat(time, ".");
strcat(time, itoa(tm->tm_mday));
strcat(time, "_");
strcat(time, itoa(tm->tm_hour));
strcat(time, ":");
strcat(time, itoa(tm->tm_min));
strcat(time, ":");
strcat(time, itoa(tm->tm_sec));
```

Comment: @BernatPedrolVozmediano My own answer looks dirty for me as well. I am giving him an solution for the expression `bin.time = tm-> tm_mon+1"."tm->tm_mday"_"tm->tm_hour":"tm->tm_min":"tm->tm_sec;` If someone provides a good solution I will delete my answer. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Later can I convert whole string into hex value using strtol?

Comment: Yes, try with `strtol(bin.time, NULL, 16)`

Comment: `bin.time` is not a string however, it's a `uint32_t` so not sure how this helps

Comment: @BernatPedrolVozmediano, if you want it optimized, save the time in the structure it's already in.